# Problem: Values from a transaction(web3) are not stored in datastucture defined by Solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js

First of all i use Truffle and Ganache.

I made a smart contract with solidity defining the following structures:

```
struct TimestampproTeil {
    uint Fahrwerk;
    uint Chaussy;
    uint Kabine;
    uint Auspuff;
}

struct Traktor {
    uint produktionsnummer;
    Kabine kab;
    Reifen reif;
    Fahrwerk fahrw;
    Chaussy chau;
    Auspuff ausp;
    TraktorTyp typ;
    uint timestamp;
    TimestampproTeil teile;
}
```

and in order to interact with the blockchain i use ganache-cli.

My API looks like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');
const path = require('path');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3("http://127.0.0.1:8545");

//Contract
const input = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/contracts/ProductionSimple.sol', 'UTF-8');
//Amount of contracts
const output = solc.compile(input, 1);

const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':ProductionSimple'].interface);
const bytecode = output.contracts[':ProductionSimple'].bytecode;

//contract 
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

const instance = myContract.deploy({
    data: bytecode
})
.send({
    from: '0x52750243c1d99839e2267c2805fe0c81261e2325', 
    gas:6721975
})
.then((newContractInstance) => {
    return newContractInstance; // instance with the new contract address
});

instance.then((legocontract) =>{
    legocontract.methods.getTimeAuspuff(3).call((err, result) => { console.log(result)})
})

instance.then((legocontract) =>{
    legocontract.methods.setTimeAuspuff(1).send({from: '0x52750243c1d99839e2267c2805fe0c81261e2325',gas:6721975});
})

instance.then((legocontract) =>{
    legocontract.methods.getTimeAuspuff(1).call((err, result) => { console.log(result)})
})
```

The functions i used for the transaction

```
function getTimeAuspuff(uint prodNr)view public returns(uint){
        return(traktoren[prodNr].teile.Auspuff);
    }

    function setTimeAuspuff(uint prodNr) public{
        uint day = now;
        traktoren[prodNr].teile.Auspuff = day;
    }
```

SetTimeAusPuff() changes the Auspuff value in TimestampproTeil and getTimeAuspuff() returns this value. 
When i interact with the node console everthing works fine for me and i can call sender functions adding new or changing values.
When i just run the whole file a new block gets generated but it does not create new values or change already existing values. Also there is no error message that occurs. So what can i do in order to fix this problem?

I use web3 version 1.0.0-beta.37 because with higher versions ganache-cli ends up in an endless loop.

Thanks for your help guys!

Updated Code:

```
const instance = async () => {
    const legocontract = await myContract.deploy({
       data: bytecode
    }).send({
    from: '0x51668bbc9278666a06d6731fe081f179e3ec934c', 
    gas:6721975
    })
    .then((newContractInstance) => {
        return newContractInstance; // instance with the new contract address
    })
    return legocontract;
};



instance().then((contract) =>{
    const getTime = async () => {
      await contract.methods.getTimeAuspuff(1).call().then((result) => { console.log(result)})
      await contract.methods.setTimeAuspuff(1).send({from: '0x51668bbc9278666a06d6731fe081f179e3ec934c',gas:6721975})
      await contract.methods.getTimeAuspuff(1).call().then((result) => { console.log(result)})
    };
    getTime().then((time) =>{
    })
})
```

Comment: Please get rid of all those screenshots, and post your code in plain text (indented 4 spaces to the right).

Comment: Sry, this is my first time asking a question.. hope i got i right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is caused by the promises you use them but do not await/chain for the result. From the commandline they will finish before you type/past the next command, but from a script it will run immediately before it finishes.

```
async function main() {
  const legocontract = await myContract.deploy({
    data: bytecode
  })
  .send({
    from: '0x52750243c1d99839e2267c2805fe0c81261e2325',
    gas:6721975
  })

  const before = await legocontract.methods.getTimeAuspuff(3).call()
  console.log(before);

  await legocontract.methods.setTimeAuspuff(1).send({
    from: '0x52750243c1d99839e2267c2805fe0c81261e2325',
    gas:6721975
  })

  const after = await legocontract.methods.getTimeAuspuff(1).call()
  console.log(after);
}

main()
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I found out that the contract address was null for this transaction. 
But for await i need async functions. Is there a way to write the code without all the nesting? I will add the updated code to the question.

Comment: You can wrap the code inside an `async` function and only use await so you don't have to pass callbacks to `then()`. If you want to manage error you have to enclose in a try/catch but otherwise IMHO it is more readable.